Is there a kit I can buy to convert my trikes bottom bracket
I have a trike that I'm rebuilding and I really don't like the square tapered bottom bracket that's on it and I'm wondering if there is a kit I can buy that converts it to a more modern 3 peace crank set that has sealed bearings that isn't a square tapered crank. I really hate the square tapered crank like really really really badly they once killed my uncle Darryl in an unfortunate biking accident.

Can you please share more details about the trike you own, or photos of the bottom bracket and how it is now connected to the trike? There are many options and wildly different solutions.

Depending on the type of the BB housing in your frame, you can fir it basicalky any kind of bottom bracket and a compatible crankset. Most likely you have a BSA (but check!) threaded housing.
You just select a crankset compatible with the rest of your drivetrain (number of chainrings, chainring sizes, chainline - I do not know what a trike needs) and then you buy the right bottom bracket that the crankset requires.
Modern bicycle cranksets are 2-piece, the axle (spindle?) is integrated with one of the cranks. 3-piece are mostly restricted to square taper and Shimano Octalink, which never really bocome very widespread and is relatively obsolete, even though you can find it even in some new bikes.
If you actually mean a BMX 3-piece crankset, you should be able to use an Euro BB style threaded bottom bracket with a BSA housing and something similar with other types. But knowing the housing of the frame is important.
